# Ideas for incorporating RTOS into a simple sensor interfacing project for learning purpose

Tags: c, embedded, sensors, rtos

I am trying to switch to embedded from a software test role, and been working on learning about STM32, and almost finishing up writing drivers for I2C which I used for interfacing with a sensor. I have looked at a lot of job descriptions and most of them do find having an understanding of RTOS essential and I'm wondering if I can incorporate in my existing simple project in any way. One approach I thought of was maybe have two threads with one reading values off the sensor while the other displaying on the screen. Not sure if RTOS is really essential for this specific use-case but just a thought.

Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Please do not cross post across multiple sites. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491460/incorporating-rtos-into-a-simple-sensor-interfacing-project-for-learning-purpose. Also this question is perhaps too broad for either site.

Comment: @Lundin - I find this question quite OK, so I'll try to answer it if you don't mind.

Comment: @HelpingHand - you can respond to this question at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/491460/incorporating-rtos-into-a-simple-sensor-interfacing-project-for-learning-purpose

Comment: @HelpingHand - or you can respond here. I don't mind

Comment: After writing the Stack Overflow answer, I checked out the corresponding discussion thread on the electronics stack ("Can you form a committee to screw in a light bulb? You sure can!" – @DKNguyen). Don't feel embarrased for creating such a tiny firmware using RTOS. This is how one learns new techniques. If you were learning how to run a committee (studying management), they would have you discuss hours about a single light bulb (lol), and your two-task RTOS firmware has the same character and meaning. Don't worry!

Answer (score 1):

#### Preface

As I understand your question, you are thinking how to write your own RTOS project to make some of your first steps in *embedded programming using an RTOS* after you did some HAL programming, working as a tester for a while, now trying to "grow" from a tester role into a developer role (It is at least questionable whether going from testing to development always means growing, but at least some areas tend to reward developers better than testers.).

I therefore assume that you know how to make an embedded software application on STM32 based on a main-loop architecture.

> Any ideas are appreciated

Your question is formulated very open, so I dare to try sketching a plan how you can make your (entire) personal education project. My apologies to those readers who find this answer to extensive.

#### 1. RTOS two-tasks example, from sensor to display?

The example you mentioned is quite a famous textbook example for your endeavour because it is perfect to demonstrate what an RTOS is good for in the context of a textbook: Supporting the functional decomposition of two quite unrelated system components by deploying them to different tasks.

It is a different question whether this is a good example application to learn actually integrating an RTOS for your personal education purpose. This depends on the familiarity with the things you do inside those two tasks, which should be as great as possible so you can focus well on the specifics of RTOS-driven SW architecture. One task ("IN") handles

> reading values off the sensor

- I assume that you are using the I²C sensor you have already dealt with. - Perfect! The other task ("OUT") deals with

> displaying on the screen.

I have been developing RTOS firmwares for a couple of years personally, but I never really integrated an embedded display. If I were to execute the plan for myself, I would dump the values to a different serial interface (say, the UART connected to the virtual serial port you get when using the STM32 of a plain Nucleo board) and have a terminal window on my PC be the actual display. Please adjust your personal plan to your own tech experience.

#### 2. Prepare your software for RTOS

Start with what you already do well: Make a main-loop firmware running correctly on your target, where you separate the two features nicely, taking care to have a nice and lean interface between those two parts (IN component only communicating to OUT what it needs to know). Most important, the interface for IN to put data updates into OUT shall be event-driven, not polling, i.e., IN calls function only if there is something to update, and OUT is not calling any function to "sniff" whether IN has some new information to report.

At the moment, both components shall have a "tick" function called from the main loop so that either component does everything it needs for itself inside that function. E.g., the IN task periodically triggers a get-data request at the I²C peripheral (or its DMA), using your driver.

#### 3a. Add RTOS to the monolith firmware

Now, please integrate the RTOS library so that it runs a single task which contains your former main loop. Hint: The old main loop becomes your one-and-only "default task", and the main() function ends after the start-RTOS call (and maybe an assert statement catching any unexpected return if you made a configuration mistake). The call to start the scheduler normally will not return because the main (system) context will be superseded by an RTOS task context.

If you haven't made a decision which RTOS to choose, I suggest that you pick freeRTOS (which is OSS) and have it preconfigured by STM32CubeMX (also free of costs) so you don't have to solve every detail at a time. If you select freeRTOS, the final call to launch the RTOS will be "osKernelStart()".

Finish the setup and debug so it runs again.

#### 3b. Make it a multi-tasking software

This is when your firmware becomes a true RTOS firmware (instead of just an as-if one). You need another task - insert it in the RTOS configuration next to the task you already have, and create another task function. Task functions look like "main()" functions, consisting of a one-shot initialisation part, and an infinite loop. Remove one component from the preexisting task and place its into the new task.

Now, you must replace the "put" function call from above by inter-task communication. Set up a queue that is read by the OUT task. Everytime OUT can take a data update out of the queue, it has to apply it to "the display" (e.g., transmit a sequence of UART frames). Have the IN task put the data structure into the queue you created. Note: The queue handle (constant pointer after creation) shall be the only variable symbol both tasks see. Apart from that, the tasks shall live in different worlds.

#### 3c. Task trigger times

Assuming that your OUT task can work with a one-shot action like putting a structure of data into a DMA buffer and triggering that DMA, this task shall only run when it is fed through "its" queue from the IN task. I.e., it won't consume CPU time unless it has work to do. Assign a higher priority to this task than to the IN task.

Now, the IN task will only run while the OUT task isn't busy. For the moment - if the IN task has nothing to do, you may leave it idling until you want it to retrieve the next set of data from your sensor. Finish the code and debug it, so you have a running system again.

Of course, you don't want the IN task to consume nearly all of the CPU time, but only what it needs. Re-check your I²C driver interface and decide how often it must be called. Set up a reload timer (use a HW timer or SW timer as you wish, try out the other option later). The timer callback (for HW timer: ISR handler) shall send an event to the IN task. The IN task shall listen to that event (and block while there is no event). Whenever the event comes from the timer callback, the IN task wakes up, gets the data from the sensor, puts it into the queue to OUT and waits for the next event to be blocked again.

Now you need an idle task, which the RTOS wakes up while all productive tasks are blocked. IMHO, the idle task shall not do anything, but this is subject to philosophic debate. Re-finish coding and debug. Find your system running again, smile and have some ice cream :-)

#### 4. Adding further goodies

You mastered the key points, now deepen your RTOS knowledge/experience by the following points:

- Check all kinds of inter-process communication your RTOS library offers, try them out inside your system.
- Add further tasks with fancy stuff. E.g., use another queue/task to drive an LED depending on sensor values.
- Set up SWV trace/debug and investigate the load produced by each task (ITM/SWO) as well as the runtime state at arbitrary breakpoint moments.
- Tidy up your code and find out where to put module boundaries.
- Use an Operating System Abstraction Layer on top of your RTOS.

Comment: I really appreciate you writing a detailed message. 

And yeah I thought of dumping the data into serial terminal instead of LED, that way I'll also learn about UART in-depth, but that will be solely used as an output interface more than input, yeah? Regarding the IN and OUT interfaces, in this context, IN would request the data from the I2C driver for data and once it's read, it will send the data to OUT interface (UART) to display in serial monitor?

Comment: Regarding triggering IN interface, you mentioned about a timer. So it would work by setting a timer to call IN to read data at specific intervals, say 3s. So every 3 seconds, it would wake IN interface which will then collect data and send to the OUT interface for displaying. What if the time it takes for the IN to get the entire data is longer than before the request comes in to read the next set of bytes? I'm pretty sure I'll have more questions while I'm at it. @HelpingHand

Comment: First of all, maybe 3 s is not what your application requires. From your non-RTOS SW, you know how frequent the sensor shall produce data. This should be the trigger period for the IN task. If the trigger processing time (read out data from sensor, send a message to OUT, receive the message by OUT, put data to output interface by OUT) is longer than your input period, then it's a load problem. It could be that your CPU is too slow, but (much) more likely, you still have some beginner's mistake in your task design...

Comment: ...When you added RTOS, you shall not do any busy waiting. Avoid any `while(MY_HW_REG != HW_REG_IDLE);` loops or similar. Some activity may trigger a request to the sensor (say, filling I²C buffer for transmission). Then, IN task shall wait blocking until I²C ISR tells it there's sensor response data. Same applies to the OUT task - you should try to transfer output data without intermediate busy waiting (OUT task shall block for some "transmit-not-empty" event from HW if data transfer is more than a single "word"). Don't worry, there are a lot of "style changes" you will get used to soon.

Comment: well currently I don't have any such timing. The whole idea of RTOS is along the lines of using a timer to trigger the IN interface to get the data every x interval of time except there's no blocking code? I was wondering if I should start off with writing a timer to read data continuously, which I think could be a good start? 
also, if the time to get the data is smaller than the frequency at which next data is to be read, that's more of a requirement issue than a design considering HW constraints, no?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly. What do you mean by `except there's no blocking code`? If you are planning to evaluate your sensors continuously (which actually means "periodically"), this is a very good idea. Unless the IN task is supposed to collect some measurement cycles and calculate an average or so, it shall pass *every* measurement value along to OUT, which updates the GUI (or output serial interface...). You can try this out at a slower pace and measure times to see which frequency your system can achieve this way.

Comment: you can't have a blocking code in RTOS from my understanding, yeah? I was asking how different would having a timer call IN at specific interval for retrieving data and passing it onto OUT than having a timer do the same within an RTOS?

Comment: (1) Technically, in an RTOS system you *can* write a task that blocks for some condition, but it isn't a smart idea because this consumes CPU time other tasks could make use of, without creating benefit. The only case when this is OK is when "active blocking" is shorter than the overhead of a context change. (2) The biggest advantage from using RTOS are (a) that you can use RTOS to wake up OUT when IN passes data to it, and (b) that both tasks can be suspended until a timer (or another interrupt) triggers, and you can easily process a third thing during this period.

Comment: (2) Sorry I'm still learning RTOS but couldn't you do the same (waking up OUT when IN is ready) with a timer in a bare-metal setting?

Comment: Don't worry about asking. The difference is that without an RTOS, a timer cannot really *wake up the OUT task* but then, the OUT task is polling for some flag set by the timer/ISR. With an RTOS, the timer can trigger some RTOS event (i.e., an event the kernel is aware of). If the task was in *WAITING* state because it blocked at the event reception API, it becomes *READY* and will start *RUNNING* as soon as no higher-prio task needs to run first (which can be at once if there is no other task). That means, it is the timer ISR that actually wakes up a suspended task, without polling!

Comment: from what I know, timers trigger a specific event upon reaching the count to whatever's in autoload register (as an example) but is this what you're referring to as polling in a bare-metal setting, that the OUT task "waits" for the timer to hit that value so it could get triggered and while it's waiting, there's nothing else happening in the execution?

Comment: The (HW) timer works as you described: The counter reaches the goal value, a HW event is created in the µC. This event can trigger other peripherals (ADC, DMA, ... - is not what we're interested in now!) and/or it can trigger an interrupt (on STM32 through NVIC). When the interupt (and interruptions in general) are activated, the timer event will cause execution to jump to the code of an ISR handler. On bare metal, your only option is to set some flag/data in RAM, or execute some activity directly. With RTOS, the ISR code can trigger the RTOS event I described, and thereby wake up a task.

Comment: by setting the flag/data for timers, you mean something like `if (TIMER_IT() == SET) WAKE_UP_OUT();` in bare-metal?

Comment: This looks like polling the HW registers, which is another "polling" option (I didn't even think of) besides setting a user (flag) variable in ISR handler user code, and polling that variable in main context. Those approaches are both more or less equivalent, and inferior to using the RTOS measures once you have integrated the RTOS.